# Is it possible to use server side rendering with existing server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering

I have nodejs + express server for API and I'm supposed to build SPA using latest Angular. The SPA should have a couple of static HTML pages which should be rendered using server side rendering and some templating engine - probably Nunjucks. My question is, is it possible to use that existing API server for server side rendering? SPA + static pages should be under one repository/directory, API server is under another. API server will be under separate domain. Is it possible to have them under separate projects or is it only possible if I combine server and SPA into a single project? The latter I assume being a pain to maintain.

Comment: An airplane can carry both human passengers and hungry lions at the time. The question is "_should it_". So yes, anything is possible if you want to completely ignore all of the lessons learned through 100ks of projects trying to accomplish these types of infrastructures. (https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can definitely use your existing node and express server. @angular/universal is used for Server Side Rendering. 
There will be separate Files for Server Configurations.

My Suggestion would be to make separate Repository for Angular app and let your existing one be as-is, that will help to maintain it better.

Please Follow "https://angular.io/guide/universal"

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that guide assumes you use server-side rendering (i.e. node server) within your angular app - which is exactly what I want to avoid. I want to have one node server for api, and angular app. I dont want one server for api, one for ssr in angular app and angular app. All I can see in that guide is that it explains how to add nodejs server to existing angular app. Can you point me to the part I'm missing?